# Why can't we do 'if (object)' in C# to test if object is null?

Tags: c#, c, object, null

In C, in order to test if a pointer is null we can do:

- `if (p != NULL)`
- `if (p != 0)`
- `if (p)`

Why isn't there any equivalent in C# that would allow us to do the following?

```
if (object)
```

instead of

```
if (object != null)
```

Comment: Why bother? `if (object != null)` is much more readable and descriptive than `if (object)`

Comment: Since when is `C# == C`? Just because C has a certain language feature, it doesn't mean C# should also have it.

Comment: @Polynomial: I find the other way more readable in fact.

Comment: @Oded: Since when did I say `C# == C`?

Comment: Never mind the readability... from the POV of types this is plain wrong.

Comment: @Otiel: You mean "I find more readable the other way". The other way is also called "Yoda expression".  ;)

Comment: I guess votes down doesn't mean anymore what it should mean :) I am asking *why*, not *how*, not saying that we should be able to do it...

Comment: Even though people may disagree with this, it's still a valid, clear and useful question, and doesn't deserve to be downvoted.

Comment: @Otiel: I'm not one of the downvoters but I assume people are not keen on questions which boil down to "Why doesn't language X have this feature from language Y?". There isn't really a good answer usually.

Comment: @Mauricio: I agree, he's asking an honest question about why they opted not to allow it.  If the post had been a "C# sucks because it can't do this neat trick" that would have been another story :-)

Comment: C is very loose with its static typing, so that NULL == 0 == false.  Note that some programs historically used a different pointer value to indicate invalid, like 0xDEADBEEF, to discriminate between uninitialized by chance (zero memory) and explicitly marked as invalid.  In such cases, the shortcut syntax (that worked by accident of convention of NULL == 0) would break down.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because tests of that nature could lead to unexpected bugs in programs, thus they favored  requiring boolean expressions to be explicit (as did Java), instead of performing an *implicit* conversion to `bool`.

This is also the same reason why you cannot use an `int` as a boolean expression in C#.  Since the only valid boolean expressions are expressions that evaluate directly to `bool`, this keeps unexpected errors from being introduced in the code, such as the old C gotcha:

```
if (x = 5)
{ 
   // always true
}
```

So, in short, it was not included in order to favor readability and explicitness.  Yes, it does come at a *slight* cost in brevity, but the gains in reduction of unexpected bugs **more** than make up for the cost of hainvg to add `!= null` inside the parenthesis...

(You can, of course, create an implicit conversion of a custom type to `bool`, as a workaround, but you can't globally apply that to any object type)

Comment: `if (x = 5)` doesn't have anything to do with that, does it? That bug is all about having an assignment allowed in that place or not, it has nothing to do with the question if `null` can be implicitly converted to `false`... Or does C# allow assignment in that place, so that `if (launchMissiles = true) ...` will compile and go horribly wrong?

Comment: @sth: It's a combination, x = 5 is an implicit conversion from `int` to `bool` in C, which is the main issue.  Note that you **can** have assignments in `if` statements in C#, as long as they are `bool` assignments.  Such as, as you said, `if (launchMissles = true)`.  If the end result is a `bool`, it can legally be used in an expression.  Also, you can do assignments in an `if` as long as the evaluation is bool`, such as `if ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)`

Comment: I'd say the main issue is that you have an assignment where you intended a comparison, not that the result of that is convertible to bool. If the intention is really to avoid such erroneous assignments, to me that looks like a rather hacky workaround around the main issue...

Comment: @sth: Unfortunately though, assignments evaluate to what they are assigned to, this allows for results of assignments to be used in comparisons and allows us to chain expressions together.  Thus, the only place this really because an issue is an accidental assignment to bool in an `if`, but these tend to be pretty rare since we don't usually say `== true` or `== false` since we can just omit and test the expression directly.

Comment: Also, `if (launchMissiles = true)` will give you a warning. Microsoft doesn't want to be blamed for a nuclear war.

Comment: @configurator - true!  Just like when they decided, "hey, maybe `format c:` should actually make sure you really want to do that..."

Comment: @harold: Sure, but you'd have to implement it for each class (or a common base class), and they have detractions as well, for the reduction in safety, i personally (just my $0.02) don't think it's worth it.

Answer (score 14):

> Why isn't there any equivalent in C# that would allow us to do the following?

In order to be used a feature must first be:

- thought of
- designed
- specified
- approved
- implemented
- tested
- shipped

The feature you mention has been thought of. It has not been designed, specified or approved by the design committee, it has not been implemented by the development team, it has not been tested, and it has never shipped in any product. Therefore you cannot use the feature.

If that doesn't answer your question then *ask a better question*. Asking why a language doesn't have a feature is like asking why a box is empty. Every empty box is empty for the same reason: **because there's nothing in it**. Every unavailable feature is unavailable because it was never shipped to customers, and there's not much more to say about it.

Comment: Well I was mostly asking the **reasons** for which the feature has not been *shipped*, the reasons behind the choices. Of course I wasn't waiting for an answer like "because there isn't" to my question "why isn't there?"... ;)

Comment: @Otiel: I assure you that we do not require *reasons* to *not ship* something. Not shipping a feature is *free* and *automatic*. It is rare indeed that we have a *specific reason* to not ship a feature that was never designed, specified, approved, implemented or tested! The fact that the feature was never designed, etc, is reason enough to explain why it could not be shipped, wouldn't you say? I'm still having difficulty understanding what you're really asking here.

Comment: I agree and get your point, my concern was only to understand why a basic and useful (at least it was to my eyes) feature has not been *designed, specified,... and shipped* in C#.

Comment: @Otiel I'd venture a guess and say that they don't want to introduce a boolean comparison / object->null comparision ambiguity into the language.

Comment: @Otiel: The reason is that the language designers found the feature to be confusing and error prone, not basic and useful.

Answer (score 9):

Technically speaking it doesn't work because there is no [implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) possible from your custom object class to `bool` (boolean). As long as you provide an implicit conversion operator, that might check your object for null, you can go ahead with your syntax:

```
    public static implicit operator bool(MyType p)
    {
        return (p != null) && (p != 0);
    }
```

**Integrating the suggestion by [Dan Bryant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206394/dan-bryant):**

An alternative way is to implement implicit "true" and "false" operators for your data type. You might need this if your type allow tri-state evaluation to `bool`: true, false and null. This is quite a common case in databases where the null value designates missing data. Here is an example from the [MSDN webpage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6x6y6z4d.aspx):

```
public static bool operator true(DBBool x)
{
    return x.value > 0;
}

public static bool operator false(DBBool x)
{
    return x.value < 0;
}
```

Comment: Good point, it could work, but I would not recommend doing it.

Comment: Neither would I! But sometimes one needs it, like I needed it in my own  DSL to allow the constructions similar to above-mentioned.

Comment: Regardless of whether we agree philosophically with doing this or not, a valid answer exists and this is it, so here's my +1 for your awesome response!

Comment: Another interesting point is that there is actually a 'true' operator which would be evaluated for this particular syntax.  There is an equivalent 'false' operator, as well.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x6y6z4d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Also, minor quibble, but you would have to name the parameter @object in that particular example, as object is a reserved word.

Answer (score 4):

Because that's how the language designers designed the language. Partially it's to prevent dumb mistakes like:

```
if (p = 42)
```

Comment: Isn't it the contrary? Wouldn't the C feature prevent those *dumb mistakes*? If you do `if (p = null)` by mistake, it's because you wanted to write `if (p == null)` or `if (p != null)`. Writing `if (p)` *would* prevent dumb mistakes.

Comment: @otiel if p is not of type boolean, this won't even compile. But let me provide a better example.

Answer (score 3):

Because an Object is not a Pointer, it is an Object.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is not in C# specification and the compiler does not understand such expression.

And if you are after the reason why it is not used in this way in C# - from my point of view it is totally illogical to check something for null in a manner if(object).

If object what?

Answer (score 1):

Your example looks readable only because your object is named 'object'.  In reality objects have names that derive from their use/function.  If your object was called 'validatedWidget' then your code would look like

```
if (validatatedWidget)
{
    // do something
}
```

Which would incorrectly imply something where as:

```
if (validatedWidget != null)
{
   // do something
}
```

Is far more explicit, and is hardly a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of if statement is ::

```
if(condition)
```

and the result of condition should be boolean i.e. true or false.

So we do write any condition like

```
x = 10;
if(x == 10)
```

but if(object) does not make a specific condition to result out as a boolean result.

if we write

```
 boolean object = true;
 if(object)
```

then it will be perfectly fine.

but to see if any object is null or not we can't write if(object) we need to write it as if(object == null) or if(object != null), because such conditions will result in boolean result.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of **why** it wasn't allowed. You're just restating the premise of the question (that it is not allowed)